# While I set up my WordPress into localhost, then search url-link in browser then see this?

Tags: wordpress

> **<?php /**  * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads  * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells
> WordPress to load the theme.  *  * @package WordPress  */ /**  * Tells
> WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.  *  * @var bool
> */ define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', true ); /** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */ require **DIR** . '/wp-blog-header.php';**

Answer (score 0):

Your webserver isn't set up to serve PHP correctly. How exactly are you setting this up?